# Why qemu doesn't install aarch64 alpine Image on x86_64 ubuntu host?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, x86, alpine-linux

I download `qemu-4.0.0.tar.xz` from [here](https://download.qemu.org/) and after installing all necessary dependencies I run `$ ./configure --target-list=aarch64-softmmu` to have `QEMU` installed. I double-check the installation with `$ qemu-system-aarch64 --version` which returns `QEMU emulator version 4.0.0` `Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers`. I proceed to build the disk image with `$ sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine-img.qcow2 10G` which returns `Formatting 'alpine-img.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=10737418240 cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16`. I download `alpine-virt-3.12.1-aarch64.iso` and `alpine-standard-3.12.1-aarch64.iso` from [here](https://www.alpinelinux.org/downloads/) and for both of them when I run `sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -cdrom alpine-image.iso -machine virt -m 1024 -smp 4 -hda alpine-img.qcow2` I get a `QEMU` window which does not proceed with installation, stays there forever, and says `compat_monitor0 console` `QEMU 4.0.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information` `(qemu)`. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT 1:** The following command also didn't work: `$ sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -boot d -cdrom alpine-standard-3.12.1-aarch64.iso -machine virt -m 1024 -smp 4 -hda alpine-img.qcow2`

**EDIT 2:** Adding the `-device virtio-gpu-pci` command, i.e., `sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -boot d -cdrom alpine-standard-3.12.1-aarch64.iso -machine virt -m 1024 -smp 4 -hda alpine-img.qcow2 -device virtio-gpu-pci` opens up the window but this time says: **Guest has not initialized the display (yet)**. The post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675013/guest-has-not-initialized-the-display-yet-when-starting-to-run-vm-that-is-ppc#:%7E:text=It%20is%20just%20QEMU%20telling,crashed%20before%20it%20got%20anywhere.) says "*This isn't an error. It is just QEMU telling you that the guest OS has not yet done what it needs to do to turn on the emulated graphics card and display output.
In this case the likely reason for this is that you've tried to run a kernel that won't work on this board model, and so it has crashed before it got anywhere. You can also see this message if the kernel has no graphics support built in and is just doing output to serial console.*"

**EDIT 3:** The `-nographic` option from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809557/no-display-with-messageguest-has-not-initialized-the-display-yet-when-i-tr) also doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT 4:** I tried the same process with `ubuntu-16.04.7-server-arm64.iso` and same results...It seems something must be wrong with my build of `QEMU`.

**EDIT 5:** I was asked if there's a reason for using an older version of `QEMU`. The issue is not related to the version of `QEMU` as it happens for `v5.2.0-rc4` as well.

**EDIT 6:** Definitely take a look at the answer to the post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1397991/running-alpine-linux-on-qemu-arm-guests/1399137#1399137). My conclusion is that just forget about the `.iso` files. Instead download the `vmlinuz-lts` kernel and `initramfs-lts` initrd files from [here](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/releases/aarch64/netboot/) and just go with something like this:

`qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a57 -kernel vmlinuz-lts -initrd initramfs-lts -append "console=ttyAMA0 ip=dhcp alpine_repo=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/" -nographic`

Make sure that you're in the directory that the kernel and initrd files are located and definitely use the `-nographic` option since it didn't work for me otherwise. I haven't yet figured out the details of what exactly is happening. Once I do I'll add an answer. Nevertheless, with the command above you'll finally see the Alpine Linux welcome page!

**EDIT 7:** The command above doesn't address `modloop` issues during the boot. You can find the `modloop` for alpine LTS or edge releases [here](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/releases/aarch64/netboot/). Accordingly, the command should change to `qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a57 -kernel vmlinuz-lts -initrd initramfs-lts -append "console=ttyAMA0 ip=dhcp alpine_repo=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ modloop=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/releases/aarch64/netboot/modloop-lts" -nographic`. You can check [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/S390x/Installation) for more details.

**EDIT 8:** I added the `-hda` flag to the final command to actually install Alpine on an image disk I created using `qemu-img`. I run `alpine-setup` and it gets to `Available disks are:` which I only have a `vda` option. So I choose it and then I'm asked `How would you like to use it?` and my options are `sys`, `data`, `lvm`....I pick `sys` and get `ERROR:unable to select packages:` `syslinux (no such package):` `required by: world[syslinux]`. Does this actually have something to do with the disk image I specified? By the way, without the `-hda` option there is no question about installing alpine whatsoever. So for installation an install option (maybe `-hda`) should be passed to the `qemu` command.

**EDIT 9:** [This](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Bootloaders) link says that by default Alpine uses Syslinux as bootloader. Also, while the package seems to be available [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/syslinux), using `apk add syslinux` Alpine doesn't return anything...Clearly during the install stage of Alpine on Disk, syslinux is being searched for and not found...

**EDIT 10:** The answer by @rudib worked like a charm for me. As for the `QEMU_EFI-pflash.raw` file you can find it in a `rpm` package [here](https://www.kraxel.org/repos/jenkins/edk2/). Just go for the `aarch64` entry and simply extract the `QEMU_EFI-pflash.raw` file.

**EDIT 11:** Just one last point: If you want to write in the shared directory, make sure to run `QEMU` as root (`sudo`) from the host considering that the answer uses the `passthrough` security model! For more info on this see [here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup).

**EDIT 12:** In case you want to use `samba` (i.e., `qemu smb`) you can use the `qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine virt -m 4096 -cpu cortex-a57 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=path_to_efi_file/QEMU_EFI-pflash.raw -drive format=raw,readonly,file=path_to_alpine_virt_iso/alpine-virt-3.12.1-aarch64.iso -drive file=path_to_qcow2_file/alpine.qcow2 -net nic -net user,smb=path_of_shared_folder` command in the host and in the guest after installing the cifs-utils [package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/cifs-utils): `mount -t cifs //10.0.2.4/qemu mount_point (e.g. /mnt)`. You can read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#QEMU%27s_built-in_SMB_server) where `qemu` and `10.0.2.4` come from in the previous command.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117003/discussion-on-question-by-newbie-why-qemu-doesnt-install-aarch64-alpine-image-o).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Install

I've successfully used these commands to boot up the alpine image and install it to a `qcow2` image:

```
# create qcow2 image
qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine.qcow2 10G

# boot up with install medium
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-machine virt -cpu cortex-a57 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file="/usr/share/edk2/aarch64/QEMU_EFI-pflash.raw" \
-m 512M \
-drive format=raw,readonly,file=/path/to/alpine-standard-3.12.1-aarch64.iso \
-drive file=alpine.qcow2
```

You need the `edk2` package on your host or obtain the file `QEMU_EFI-pflash.raw` by other means.

Then, you can run `setup-alpine` and install sys on `/dev/vdb` (`alpine.qcow2`).
`setup-alpine` seems to work out of the box just fine here.

After completing the install, shut down the system and remove the install medium:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-machine virt -cpu cortex-a57 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file="/usr/share/edk2/aarch64/QEMU_EFI-pflash.raw" \
-m 512M \
-drive file=alpine.qcow2
```

You should now have booted into your new alpine install.

## Graphics

If you want graphics, you can add:

```
# ramfb seems to work (altough it wont be fast)
-device ramfb
# or virtio gpu, should be faster, but will be detected later
-device virtio-gpu
```

You'll also need to add peripherals if you want to interact with the vm:

```
-device usb-ehci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse
```

## Shared Folder

If you wanted to share a folder, you could use 9p or maybe the included samba server. 9p should work like this (as in the [qemu documentation](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup)):

```
-fsdev local,path=/path/to/your/folder,security_model=none,id=test_dev \
-device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=test_dev,mount_tag=test_mount
```

And in the guest:

```
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio test_mount /mnt
```